# SQL Server 2008 - Return a text string in a new column based upon criteria in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

```
select PERSONNUM, PAYCODENAME as StraightTime, PAYCODENAME as OT
from dbo.VP_ALLTOTALS
where OT in ('Overtime', 'Double Overtime') 
return 'OT',
and StraightTime in ('Straight Time Earnings', 'Sunday Premium')
return 'Straight Time'
```

Comment: Show sample data and a desired result.

Comment: Just Looking for logic help here. Would like to have a column return either "OT" or "Straight Time"

Comment: Just Looking for logic help here. 
Would like to have a column return either "OT" or "Straight Time" based on the parameters in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're looking for  `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ot IN ( 'Overtime', 'Double Overtime' ) THEN ot 
         WHEN straighttime IN ( 'Straight Time Earnings', 'Sunday Premium' ) 
            THEN straighttime 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS ColumnName 
FROM   dbo.vp_alltotals
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cfcc3/1/0)

or, if you just want to return the string `OR` / `Straight Time`:

```
 SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ot IN ( 'Overtime', 'Double Overtime' ) THEN 'OT'
         WHEN straighttime IN ( 'Straight Time Earnings', 'Sunday Premium' ) 
            THEN 'straighttime' 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS Type
FROM   dbo.vp_alltotals
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cfcc3/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

Where clauses are filters only...put the logic into the select line using a case statement.

```
select PERSONNUM, PAYCODENAME as StraightTime, PAYCODENAME as OT
case when OT in ('Overtime', 'Double Overtime')  then 'OT',
when StraightTime in ('Straight Time Earnings', 'Sunday Premium') then 'Straight Time'
else 'not in list?' end as 'returnedcode' --name your new column here
from dbo.VP_ALLTOTALS
```